# Is 1/2 inch OSB strong enough for subfloor

Tags: flooring, structural, subfloor, sound-proofing

We just found out that the subfloors in our rental property are only 1/2 inch thick OSB.  It has some moisture damage but we fixed what caused it and are replacing damaged ones.

We can't really afford to put down all new subfloors, and  I am either installing 5 mm LVP or possibly even a peel and stick.  Would a 1/2" OSB subfloor be sufficient for this?

Comment: I've removed the rant (though I get your pain) because it doesn't help the question, and have attempted to distill this down to the facts and the question. If you feel I've removed any relevant, important details please [edit] to reinsert them.

Comment: I _seriously_ doubt that's what you have. It wouldn't be legal in any modern jurisdiction. What's your evidence?

Comment: At least it wasn't particleboard ...

Answer (score 1):

Half-inch OSB seems to be rated at 16 inch centers, but it's pretty much the minimum.

https://codes.iccsafe.org/s/IRC2021P2/part-iii-building-planning-and-construction/IRC2021P2-Pt03-Ch05-SecR503.2.1.1

Comment: Not as a sole subfloor. Maybe in conjunction with another layer.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. Not with criminal tenants, but with the subfloor.

I hate OSB, but sometimes it's there and has to be used.  In one of my rentals I placed 4x8 sheets of [1/4 Durock](https://www.homedepot.com/p/USG-Durock-Brand-1-2-in-x-4-ft-x-8-ft-Cement-Board-with-EdgeGuard-172956/304217914) over the OSB. glued and screwed. I taped the seams just to fill in the edges.  Then installed a 6 mil vapor barrier and the LVP.

Pricing on here is verboten, but I found a good quality [LVP](https://www.flooranddecor.com/duralux-performance-flooring/winter-peak-rigid-core-luxury-vinyl-plank---foam-back-100956788.html) with a 5mm total thickness, for less than $2/ sq ft. US.

Comment: Pricing, as an example of how one method may be more economical than another isn't verboten in answers. Asking about pricing (especially for contractors) in the _question_ **is verboten**.